# Is there any function for finding the multiple particular values stored in array type column?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am looking for a function which can help me to query multiple input values on a particular column which stored as an array

Already tried using like function to search in a string

```
select *
from express_dwh.kengic_bag_seal_ad_json
where Sorter_id='KENGIC_1' and ad >='2019-08-21-0' and 
      wbns LIKE '%3008127238325%' OR wbns LIKE '%3008127259896%' OR wbns LIKE '%3008127263750%'
```

Error running query:

> SYNTAX_ERROR: line 3:56: Left side of LIKE expression must evaluate to a varchar (actual: array(varchar))

[image]

Comment: Please edit your question and explain the type of `wbns`.  Clearly, it is not a string, which it should be.  You probably need JSON functions.

Comment: Image is attached

Comment: Wbns value is stored in an array form

Comment: . . That is not possible.  MySQL does not support arrays.

Comment: The error message does not seem to come from mysql. Pls tag your question with the correct product tag.

Comment: What data type is the column `wbns`? (Looks like `json` or `jsonb`)  And do you want to search for exact matches or should `%3008127238325%` also include `999999993008127238325xxxxxx`?

Comment: It is array...I don't want exact match

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for the “overlaps” operator `&&`:

```
wbns && ARRAY[3008127238325,3008127259896,3008127263750]
```

Depending on the data type, you may need a cast like

```
wbns && ARRAY[3008127238325,3008127259896,3008127263750]::numeric[]
```

Comment: I did. I translated the conditions from the query in your question.